# What is a typical directory path for webserver docroots?

Tags: web-server, unix

Where would one typically store all the web pages and everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the distro/OS (and Webserver) but with Apache, it's usually /var/www/ (Debian/Ubuntu), /usr/local/www/ (FreeBSD), or depending on how/what you're doing, could also be in /home/user/htdocs|www|public_html.

Comment: Do you know of what is typical for Solaris?

Comment: The default Solaris configuration has /var/apache/htdocs and /var/apache2/htdocs depending if you run the 1.x or 2.x version.

Answer (score 3):

@gravyface gave a good general list of places to check.  Here's a way to determine the exact web file location on a random unix or linux system:

Run `/usr/sbin/httpd -V`, then look for two things:

```
-D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/httpd"
-D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Combining those gives you the config file location, in this case `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

Look through that file for `DocumentRoot`.  There may be more than one DocumentRoot if the system is configured for virtual hosts, find the one not in a vhost directive.

In this case, it's

```
DocumentRoot "/webdocs"
```

which tells you that the webpages are stored under `/webdocs`.

Comment: For Ubuntu it's /usr/sbin/apache2 -V and `SERVER_CONFIG_FILE` contains the whole path.